# Graph theory: weighted undirected network

Tags: r, graph

I have 21 points (A-U). I have a list of undirected arcs between two points (21 * 20 arcs). I also have weight for each arc. I want to choose some arcs to form a network to minimize the sum of weights of A and each of B-U (i.e. A and B, A and C, A and D, etc.). Which algorithm do I should use? How can I do it in R?

That corresponds to a story like this. I want to design a transportation network that can make the country capital be easily connected with the state capital.

Comment: [cs.se] may suit questions asking for algorithm better, but remember to read their help center before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the optimal path from a point to another.
To solve that, you should try using Ford-Fulkerson's algorithm. You can also use Dijkstra's algorithm, but only if you're sure you have no negative cycles

Comment: Thanks, Rabih, but both two cannot satisfy me. Let me specify more precisely. Say that I want to have a network between Washington DC and each capital of state. Dijkstra's or Ford-Fulkerson's algorithm can give the least cost path between DC and each state capital. However, it is more efficient that New York state capital is connected to DC through Pennsylvania capital, rather than two separate directed lines between DC and New York and between DC and Pennsylvania. Is it clear?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are trying to establish the most efficient graph connecting state capitals to D.C 
In that case, you're looking for the covering tree approach, in which you connect all graph vertices at a minimal cost. For that, try to check Kruskal's algorithm, or Prim's or Solen's. In general, you will be avoiding to use any cycle before covering the whole graph

Comment: Yes, I did know the minimum spanning tree algorithms.Thanks!!